# Filtering pandas dataframe with multiple Boolean columns

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, boolean

I am trying to filter a df using several Boolean variables that are a part of the df, but have been unable to do so.

Sample data:

```
A | B | C | D
John Doe | 45 | True | False
Jane Smith | 32 | False | False
Alan Holmes | 55 | False | True
Eric Lamar | 29 | True | True
```

The dtype for columns C and D is Boolean. I want to create a new df (df1)  with only the rows where either C or D is True. It should look like this:

```
A | B | C | D
John Doe | 45 | True | False
Alan Holmes | 55 | False | True
Eric Lamar | 29 | True | True
```

I've tried something like this, which faces issues because it cant handle the  Boolean type:

```
df1 = df[(df['C']=='True') or (df['D']=='True')]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: the bool type should be referenced unquoted unless it's stored as a string

Answer (score 77, accepted):

```
In [82]: d
Out[82]:
             A   B      C      D
0     John Doe  45   True  False
1   Jane Smith  32  False  False
2  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

**Solution 1:**

```
In [83]: d.loc[d.C | d.D]
Out[83]:
             A   B      C      D
0     John Doe  45   True  False
2  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

**Solution 2:**

```
In [94]: d[d[['C','D']].any(1)]
Out[94]:
             A   B      C      D
0     John Doe  45   True  False
2  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

**Solution 3:**

```
In [95]: d.query("C or D")
Out[95]:
             A   B      C      D
0     John Doe  45   True  False
2  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

PS If you change your solution to:

```
df[(df['C']==True) | (df['D']==True)]
```

it'll work too

[Pandas docs - boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

---

> [why we should NOT use "PEP complaint" `df["col_name"] is True` instead of `df["col_name"] == True`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207530/filtering-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-boolean-columns/46207540?noredirect=1#comment101065544_46207540)

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame({"col":[True, True, True]})

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
    col
0  True
1  True
2  True

In [13]: df["col"] is True
Out[13]: False               # <----- oops, that's not exactly what we wanted
```

Comment: Man, I think most of questioners were spoiled by us ...:) Nice solution

Comment: Wow so much simpler than I had expected, thank you! I ended up using solution 3 because I actually had 4 boolean variables in my actual dataset  and that one was the neatest - worked like a charm! I didn't realize that bools worked like that, i.e. that I didn't to define the content of the bool (1/0, True/False) and that it automatically assumes True. Thanks again!

Comment: Wow, you've covered all the basics. I had a hard time coming up with answers :p

Comment: if it has to be exactly 1, you could use sum `df[df[<boolean columns>].sum(axis=1) == 1`

Comment: @MaartenFabré, yes, we can still do `df[df[<boolean columns>].sum(axis=1) > 0]`, but `df[df[<boolean columns>].any(axis=1)]` is more idiomatic IMO...

Comment: that's why I would only use it if exactly 1 `True` value is asked. The OP used `either`, which may indicate one or the other, but not both

Comment: `df[(df.var == True)].count()` fires E712 (use is True instead of ==) for me

Comment: @kev, thank you for your advise, but `(df['C'] is True)` will __always__ return `False`, independently from the data. I don't think this will improve my answer ;)

Comment: @kev, i wouldn't intentionally break the code (`df["col_name"] is True` - produces a __wrong result__) just to be PEP complaint. I have added an example in the answer. BTW there are three options in my answer and all of them are PEP complaint ;)

Answer (score 15):

Hooray! More options!

#### `np.where`

```
df[np.where(df.C | df.D, True, False)]

             A   B      C      D
0     John Doe  45   True  False
2  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

---

#### `pd.Series.where` on `df.index`

```
df.loc[df.index.where(df.C | df.D).dropna()]

               A   B      C      D
0.0     John Doe  45   True  False
2.0  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3.0   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

---

#### `df.select_dtypes`

```
df[df.select_dtypes([bool]).any(1)]   

             A   B      C      D
0     John Doe  45   True  False
2  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

---

#### Abusing `np.select`

```
df.iloc[np.select([df.C | df.D], [df.index])].drop_duplicates()

             A   B      C      D
0     John Doe  45   True  False
2  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

Comment: @Wen Most of these solutions suck, but I had fun finding them.  I think `np.where` is the best one.

Comment: Cool! I'd never think of "np.select" +1 :)

Answer (score 5):

Or

```
d[d.eval('C or D')]

Out[1065]:
             A   B      C      D
0     John Doe  45   True  False
2  Alan Holmes  55  False   True
3   Eric Lamar  29   True   True
```

Comment: Eval, this was my first option! (had to look for another one after this)

Answer (score 1):

## So, the easiest way to do this:

```py
students = [ ('jack1', 'Apples1' , 341) ,
             ('Riti1', 'Mangos1'  , 311) ,
             ('Aadi1', 'Grapes1' , 301) ,
             ('Sonia1', 'Apples1', 321) ,
             ('Lucy1', 'Mangos1'  , 331) ,
             ('Mike1', 'Apples1' , 351),
              ('Mik', 'Apples1' , np.nan)
              ]
#Create a DataFrame object
df = pd.DataFrame(students, columns = ['Name1' , 'Product1', 'Sale1']) 
print(df)


    Name1 Product1  Sale1
0   jack1  Apples1    341
1   Riti1  Mangos1    311
2   Aadi1  Grapes1    301
3  Sonia1  Apples1    321
4   Lucy1  Mangos1    331
5   Mike1  Apples1    351
6     Mik  Apples1    NaN

# Select rows in above DataFrame for which ‘Product’ column contains the value ‘Apples’,
subset = df[df['Product1'] == 'Apples1']
print(subset)

 Name1 Product1  Sale1
0   jack1  Apples1    341
3  Sonia1  Apples1    321
5   Mike1  Apples1    351
6     Mik  Apples1    NA

# Select rows in above DataFrame for which ‘Product’ column contains the value ‘Apples’, AND notnull value in Sale

subsetx= df[(df['Product1'] == "Apples1")  & (df['Sale1'].notnull())]
print(subsetx)
    Name1   Product1    Sale1
0   jack1   Apples1      341
3   Sonia1  Apples1      321
5   Mike1   Apples1      351

# Select rows in above DataFrame for which ‘Product’ column contains the value ‘Apples’, AND Sale = 351

subsetx= df[(df['Product1'] == "Apples1")  & (df['Sale1'] == 351)]
print(subsetx)

   Name1 Product1  Sale1
5  Mike1  Apples1    351

# Another example
subsetData = df[df['Product1'].isin(['Mangos1', 'Grapes1']) ]
print(subsetData)

Name1 Product1  Sale1
1  Riti1  Mangos1    311
2  Aadi1  Grapes1    301
4  Lucy1  Mangos1    331
```

Here is the source of this code: https://thispointer.com/python-pandas-select-rows-in-dataframe-by-conditions-on-multiple-columns/
I added minor changes to it.

Answer (score -2):

you could try this easily:

```
df1 = df[(df['C']=='True') | (df['D']=='True')]
```

Note:

1. The `or` logical operator needs to be replaced by the bitwise `|`
   operator.
2. Ensure that `()` are used to enclose each of the operands.

Comment: This is similar to answers already given half a year before and doesn't work. Please try out on the example data the next time.