# how can I filter single column in a dataframe on multiple values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I would like to filter it by multiple values within a single column, how can I accomplish this? when I filter by a singular value I usually use `df_filtered = df[df['column'] == value]`, but that isn't working for the 61 values at least as I've tried it.

```
        MRN  ... Result
0  13556832  ...  400.0
1  13556832  ...  400.0
2  13556832  ...  400.0
3  13556832  ...  392.0
4  13556832  ...  400.0
```

here is a sample of the dataframe (there are about 100k rows), and I need to filter for the 61 MRN values that I have identified for a project. So ultimately I would like to have a separate df that includes all MRN values that I have identified as important.

I am essentially looking for a solution that is similar to the `.isin()` operator except for 61 values, not 2 max

Comment: can you provide some sample data please

Comment: Is something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207530/filtering-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-boolean-columns what you're asking about?

Comment: @aws_apprentice, I just copied the head off one of my df's and elaborated a little bit more.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put all 61 MRNs into a list-

```
mrnList = [val1, val2, ...,val61]
```

Then filter these MRNs like-

```
df_filtered = df[df['MRN'].isin(mrnList)]
```

Keep note of your MRN value's datatype while making mrnList.

Comment: I believe they are all int64, based on some quick looking.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.where` for single conditions

```
import numpy as np
df_filtered = np.where(df['column'] == value, True, False)
```

and `logical_or`, `logical_and` for multiple conditions

```
import numpy as np
cond1 = df['column'] == value
cond2 = df['column'] == value2
df_filtered = np.where(np.logical_or(cond1, cond2), True, False)
```

For filtering by a list of values `isin` comes in handy

```
whitelist = []
df_filtered = np.where(np.isin(df['value'], whitelist), True, False)
```

For filtering a complete `DataFrame` `isin` can be used like

```
df_filtered = df[df.value.isin(whitelist)]
```

Comment: Just noticed: `df_filtered = np.where(np.isin(df['value'], whitelist)), True, False)` should be `df_filtered = np.where(np.isin(df['value'], whitelist), True, False)`. There was an extra `)`