# I have a database that I want to pull specific names out of a column. The code below works well if I just passed one key through it but not multiple

Tags: python, pandas

```
Google_Crews = Test1[Test1['ExcavatorName'] == 'EBENEZER UTILITIES CONSTRUCTION LLC']
```

((the above line works))

```
Google_Crews = Test1[Test1['ExcavatorName'] == 'EBENEZER UTILITIES CONSTRUCTION LLC', 'AMA CONSTRUCTION LLC', 'AMAZING UNDERGROUND']
```

((this says invalid key))

This is the error I got when I ran multiple names through the code.

```
Name: ExcavatorName, Length: 77996, dtype: bool, 'AMA CONSTRUCTION LLC', 'AMAZING UNDERGROUND')' is an invalid key
```

Comment: You may be looking at something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59275119/how-can-i-filter-single-column-in-a-dataframe-on-multiple-values

Comment: The key is invalid because it's parsed as `(Test1['ExcavatorName'] == 'EB...'), ('AMA ...'), ('AMAZ...')`. Similar: [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True?](/q/20002503/4518341)