# Delete rows belonging to a day with less observations than a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe df with a 'Date' value, a 'Time' value and a 'X' value. I would like to delete all the days with a count of observation smaller than 388.

I tried to use the following

```
aux = df.groupby('Date')['X'].count()
for i in aux.index:
    idx = df['Date']==i
    if sum(idx)<388:
        df = df[~(idx)]
```

But it is super slow.
Is there a faster way to do it?

Comment: Might be worth giving: `df2 = df[df.groupby('Date')['X'].transform('count') >= 388]` a try?

Comment: @JonClements not an exact dupe but should suffice - can you close ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering pandas dataframe with multiple Boolean columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207530/filtering-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-boolean-columns)

Comment: @Manakin why Jon's solution is not exact? Moreover, the link you provided do not answer my question  since the indexes of df and aux are different

Comment: `aux` is just a subset of your dataframe which you obtain via looping. Since you need to subset your dataframe by a boolean I think the answer suffices.