# Vectorized Pandas method for set-like comparison against multiple boolean columns/series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, set, boolean

Sample data to illustrate:

```py
import pandas as pd

animals = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['ostrich', 'parrot', 'platypus'],
                        'legs': [2, 2, 4],
                        'flight': [False, True, False],
                        'beak': [True, True, True],
                        'feathers': [True, True, False]})
```

| name | legs | flight | beak | feathers |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ostrich | 2 |  | ✔ | ✔ |
| parrot | 2 | ✔ | ✔ | ✔ |
| platypus | 4 |  | ✔ |  |

## What already works

Pandas makes it easy to check an entire column (which is a series) against a condition, and the result (a series of booleans) can be used to filter the dataframe with [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```py
bipeds = (animals.legs == 2)
print(animals[bipeds])

          name  legs  flight  beak  feathers
0      ostrich     2   False  True      True
1       parrot     2    True  True      True
```

In my use case, each such condition is being parsed from a term in a text search string, so I need to construct them programmatically. (I'm aware of Pandas' [query](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html), but I need different functionality.) Writing a function to do this is pretty straightforward:

```py
def comp_search(df, column_name, comp, value):
    return getattr(df[column_name], f'__{comp}__')(value)

bipeds = comp_search(animals, 'legs', 'eq', 2)
```

Checking any given *boolean* column is as simple as, for instance, `animals[animals.feathers]`.

## What I'd like to do

I want to perform ***set comparisons against the collection of  boolean columns***: finding, for instance, all animals that have at least a certain set of features, or less than a set, etc. Extrapolating from earlier, I can picture such a condition looking like this:

```py
set(df[features]) <= set(values)
```

And such a condition could hypothetically be built like so:

```py
def set_comp_search(df, column_names, comp, values):
    return getattr(set(df[column_names]), f'__{comp}__')(set(values))
```

Of course neither of these work, as `set()` of a dataframe creates an ordinary set of its column names.

## What works, but is highly inefficient

The above can be achieved by using [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to convert each row of booleans into a set, then comparing against the resulting series of sets:

```py
def row_to_set(row):
    return set(label for label, value
               in zip(row.index, row)
               if value)

def set_comp_search(df, column_names, comp, values):
    series_of_sets = df[column_names].apply(row_to_set, axis=1)
    return getattr(series_of_sets, f'__{comp}__')(set(values))
```

Nice and concise! Unfortunately, iterating with `apply` becomes exceedingly slow when the source dataframe grows to thousands of rows long.

## What works, but seems like a reimplementation

If I hardcode an equivalent boolean expression for each individual set comparison like this, the resulting comparisons are vectorized (performed on entire columns, rather than iterated at the Python level).

```py
def set_comp_search(df, column_names, comp, values):
    other_column_names = set(column_names) - set(values)
    value_columns = df[values]
    other_columns = df[other_column_names]
    
    if comp == 'gt':
        # All the searched features, and at least one other
        return value_columns.all(axis=1) & other_columns.any(axis=1)

    if comp == 'ge':
        # All the searched features
        return value_columns.all(axis=1)
    
    if comp == 'eq':
        # All the searched features, and none other
        return value_columns.all(axis=1) & ~other_columns.any(axis=1)
    
    if comp == 'le':
        # No other features
        return ~other_columns.any(axis=1)
    
    if comp == 'lt':
        # Not all of the searched features, and none other
        return ~value_columns.all(axis=1) & ~other_columns.any(axis=1)
```

So if I want a condition to represent `set(animals[features]) > {'beak'}`:

```py
more_than_beak = set_comp_search(animals, {'flight', 'beak', 'feathers'},
                                 'gt', {'beak'})
# Converts to: (animals.beak) & (animals.flight | animals.feathers)
print(animals[more_than_beak])

          name  legs  flight  beak  feathers
0      ostrich     2   False  True      True
1       parrot     2    True  True      True

# Correctly omits the platypus
```

Clunkiness aside, this runs sufficiently quickly. But I feel like I must be reinventing a wheel. This seems like a roughly similar use-case to what the [`Series.str`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html) methods do, though it would need to operate with a dataframe, a sequence of series, or a numpy array, rather than a single series. (Sadly there is no `DataFrame.set` module.)

So my question is: **Does Pandas provide a vectorized method for set-like comparison against collections of boolean columns?**

*(I've also looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207530/filtering-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-boolean-columns), since it sounds similar, but it's not applicable to set-like behavior.)*

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this type of open-ended, opinion based, question is off-topic for Stack Overflow. [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) is a probably a better venue for this [type](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) of question. Please review [help/on-topic] for Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney That page you linked mentions specifically that Code Review questions have to be about real code from a project. This code runs and works, but it's clearly a simplification of what I'm actually doing. I'm not sure if it would be applicable there.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney I've also edited to clarify that while I can code my *own* implementation, I'm really trying to see if *Pandas itself* provides some sort of method/syntax/technique for this type of comparison. Thank you for helping me notice my vagueness.

Comment: @CrazyChucky I think you can for sure simplify the `set_comp_search` function..No need to use `reduce` and `operator`

Comment: @ShubhamSharma Good call! I've edited it to use Pandas' `any`/`all` methods instead. Probably more efficient that way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like you might benefit from a function that is vectorized with numpy.  Here is an example of such a function, the vectorize, and the application thereof:

```
def analyze_birds (name: str, legs: int, feathers: bool):
  if feathers and legs == 2 :
    return name + "-Feathered Biped"
  if legs > 2 :
    return name + "-Quadruped" 

vector_analyze_birds = np.vectorize(analyze_birds) 

animals['Analysis'] = vector_analyze_birds(animals['name'], animals['legs'], animals['feathers'])
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqiUr.png)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion—I was not aware of Numpy's `vectorize` method. However, its [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) says it is "provided primarily for convenience, not for performance. The implementation is essentially a for loop." It still has to iterate at the Python level, calling the function repeatedly—much like my inefficient `apply` attempt—rather than iterating the C level, like Numpy's and Pandas' own vectorized methods.

Comment: That is all true! I think it is worth mentioning that in my own practice transforming GBs and sometimes TBs of data files mostly using numpy vectorize my longest function takes about 60-90 seconds. I would be interested to learn why that is too slow for your application. In some cases I am iterating over 3-4 columns and multiple dataframes too, cheers!

Comment: 60-90 seconds would be a long time to wait for a search engine query—ideally the results are essentially instant. This set comparison cares about five columns, and the data I'm searching is about 40,000 rows. (A given text query could include *multiple* set conditions, too: not these columns, at least those columns, etc.)