# Plotting from data but only when specific critera or values are met in python (matplotlib)

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, plot, scatter

so I don't have much of an idea on how to do this at all, I know how to plot for example a scatter plot like below from a dataframe, but is there a way that I can plot for when a column meets a certain parameter, for example only on specific dates, or would I have to create new dataframes for each selection of data I want to plot and plot from there?

```
df_plot.plot(x = 'Date', y = 'Good (1) : Bad (0)', kind = 'scatter', title = ('Good Vs. Bad Data')).set_xlabel("{}{}{}{}".format(' Date ',df_plot['Date'][0],' untill ',df_plot['Date'][len(df_plot)-1]))
plt.xticks([])
```

TIA!

Comment: Very broad question with no real answer but the idea would be to use [Boolean filters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46207530/filtering-pandas-dataframe-with-multiple-boolean-columns#46208800).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, AFAIK the easiest way is to pass `DataFrame.plot` a subset of your dataframe. If your dataframe is using the date column as the index and it is a datetime column, you can select a subset like this:

```py
start_date = '1980-12-30'
end_date = '2020-02-07'
df.loc[start_date:end_date]
```

or if it is not your index:

```py
start_date = '1980-12-30'
end_date = '2020-02-07'
df['Date_column'][start_date:end_date]
```

If your column contains strings of dates, you can convert the column like this:

```py
df['Date_column'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_column'])
```